# Docker Nginx disable default exposed port 80

Tags: nginx, docker

Is there a way to disable the default `EXPOSE 80 443` instruction in the nginx docker file without creating my own image?

I'm using `Docker` `Nginx` image and trying to expose **only** port 443 in the following way:

```
docker run -itd --name=nginx-test --publish=443:443 nginx
```

But I can see using `docker ps -a` that the container exposes port 80 as well:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                     NAMES
ddc0bca08acc        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   17 seconds ago      Up 16 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp              nginx-test
```

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 3):

The `expose instruction` is in the docker file which the image is built from.
You need to create your own customized Image for that.

To get the job done:
First locate the [dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/jessie/Dockerfile) for the [official nginx (library)](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx)

Then Edit the dockerfile's `expose` instruction to `443` only.

Now build your own image modified image using official(customized) dockerfile.

To answer your edited question:

Docker uses iptables, While you could  manually update the firewall rules to make the service unavailable at a certain port, you would not be able to unbind the Docker proxy. So port 80 will still be consumed on the docker host and docker proxy.

Comment: I know it's default, is there a way to do it without creating my own image? with `docker` commands?

Comment: i think rebuild image just for expose port is no needed in this case

Comment: It is required to rebuild the image, The expose command wil still listens on port 80 but nginx service will reject it `e40ba7e86867        nginx                          "nginx -g 'daemon off"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp          nginx-test
`

Comment: if you look at dockerfile at  https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile it exposing both ports 80 443

Comment: Yeah thats the point of my answer... and the link is from my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

according to nginx docker image configuration , you can set this before container starts passing an environment var like :

```
docker run -itd -e NGINX_PORT=443 --name=nginx-test nginx
```

see :

[using environment variables in nginx configuration](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)

then in your nginx you can set :

```
listen ${NGINX_PORT};
```

Comment: This just instructs nginx service  to stops listening on port 80, docker will still consume port 80 on the docker host and docker proxy will still redirect port 80 to the container

Comment: Just do a docker ps, you will see port 80 exposed. `e40ba7e86867        nginx                          "nginx -g 'daemon off"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp          nginx-test
`

Comment: you're right but it will be never be listened by service because you're passing to listen port 443 i think i'ts not a port forwarding , just is unused ...

Comment: The point is you cant have another container listening on port 80 on the same docker host, because you are wasting it on a container that is not using it.

Comment: docker internally ports are resolved by dns on the bridge , thats why you can foward same internall ports to a host , anyway you're right and i'm agree that is a little messy leaving an unused address but i think this question is little subjective just in a manner how you want to handle it

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to free the port (but not to unexpose it). I tried avoiding to publish the port but it didn't work and I got errors about the por being already in use anyway. Until I found that the trick is to publish the exposed port but mapped to a different one.

Let me explain with an example.

This will still try to use port 80:

```
docker up -p 443:443
```

But this will use 443 and some other random port you pick

```
docker up -p 443:443 -p<some free port>:80
```

You can do this in your commands, docker-compose or ansible playbooks to be able to start more than one instance on the same machine. (ie: nginx, which exposes port 80 by default)

I do this from docker-compose and ansible too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to patch the original dockerfile then rebuilding the image. You can just edit the image's metadata to unexpose the port. See https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit